# WCF data service [WebGet] datetime parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, datetime, webget

I try to pass 2 datetime parameters into my webget but I can't figure out how to get it to work properly I will show you my code below and the error i get maybe somebody nows how this works .

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<TestTable> GetCallersByDate(string beginDate, string eindDate)
{
        testCDREntities context = this.CurrentDataSource;

        DateTime startDt = DateTime.Parse(beginDate);
        DateTime endDt = DateTime.Parse(eindDate);



        var selectedOrders = from table in context.TestTables
                             where table.Created >= startDt && table.Created <= endDt
                             select table;

        return selectedOrders; 
}
```

The url :

```
http://localhost:50088/WebService.svc/GetCallersByDate?beginDate=2016/03/23T20:22:30:14&eindDate=2016/03/2T20:13:11:03
```

I hope somebody can help me ?

Comment: At the very least those slashes will be problematic, URL encode your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data below, you should use DateTime.ParseExact instead of the usual DateTime.Parse

http://localhost:50088/WebService.svc/GetCallersByDate?beginDate=2016/03/23T20:22:30:14&eindDate=2016/03/2T20:13:11:03

We can see that the format of the date string is yyyy/MM/ddTHH:mm:ss and AFAIK that this format is not native to .NET

beginDate=2016/03/23T20:22:30:14
eindDate=2016/03/2T20:13:11:03

```
string dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/ddTHH:mm:ss";

DateTime startDt = DateTime.ParseExact(beginDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime endDt = DateTime.Parse(eindDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help you are amazing !